# When $\frac{e^{-\lambda } \lambda ^x}{x!}$ over positive integers is invertible?

Tags: functions, special-functions

I am curious for what values of $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^+$, the function $f(x)=\frac{e^{-\lambda } \lambda ^x}{x!}$ defined only on positive integers i-e $x \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ is invertible?

When $\lambda$ is any positive integer then there exists exactly one point in range of $f$ that is not invertible otherwise $f$ is one-to-one mapping ? But what can be  said about rational and irrational values of $\lambda$ ?

Comment: What do you mean "invertible?" We rarely talk about "invertible" functions from $\mathbb N\to\mathbb R$. Do you mean one-to-one?

Comment: Yes one to one.

Comment: Then the factor $e^{-\lambda}$ is a red herring. If $\lambda^n/n!$ is $1-1$ then so is $e^{-\lambda}\lambda^n/n!$, and visa versa.

Comment: But it does not answer my question.

Comment: I'm sorry for trying to help you. I'll stop now.

Comment: You are right about $\lambda$ a positive integer. When $\lambda\gt 0$ is **not** an integer, then for any non-negative integers $x$ and $y$ with $x\ne y$, we have $e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^x}{x!}\ne e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^y}{y!}$.

Comment: Andre NicolasThanks.  This is what I am interested in knowing. Would you please describe a little how did you deduce it?